# How to check particular ip address belongs to which range in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 PySpark dataframes. The 2nd dataframe consists of IP address and 1st dataframe has 3 column, 1st column starting IP address and 2 column end ip address and 3rd column has a country name.

Now I have to check the 2nd dataframe ip address column to the 1st dataframe column to know from which country it belongs??

[image: Please check the image for more details]

Comment: It would be great if you can paste the dataframe and the code you have tried, instead of the screenshot.

Comment: actually i dont know how to do this things.it will be helpful if u suggest me some idea

Comment: Ok.  You have basic awareness on pyspark? Just about RDD and dataframes.

Comment: yes...i have an data in sql dataframe.

Comment: Ok. One challenge here is, there is no common column on which both dataframes can be joined. However, I believe the solution might not be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check from which country ip belongs then go with python **geoip2** framework.
for more info refer :-  https://packagist.org/packages/geoip2/geoip2

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross join and udf to filter the records which falls into ip range

```
df1.crossJoin(df2).where( isInIpRangeUdf(df1.col("start_ip"), df1.col("end_ip"),df2.col("ip_address")) == True).show()
```

Comment: how to write udf function. and what is code to be write in it. Because i am getting error like  **name 'isInIpRangeUdf' is not defined**